# Alphabetizing query info in a listview (Visual Basic)

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, visual-studio, listview

I'm doing a programming file in which i queried the names, abbreviations, population, and area of all 50 US states in from an XML file. I am trying to output the data into a listview control with each element going into its respective column (Name goes in column name etc). I can get the names alphabetized by using the "order by name ascending" within the query, however the abbreviations and other info doesn't fall in order with the names. I tried to order the other data by name but that did nothing at all. 
example of the name query

```
        Dim QueryStates = From State In States.Descendants("state")
                      Let name = State.<name>.Value
                      Order By name Ascending
                      Select name

    NameArr = QueryStates.ToArray

    Dim queryStates2 = From state In States.Descendants("state")
                       Let abb = state.<abbreviation>.Value
                       Order By Name Ascending
                       Select abb

    abbArr = queryStates2.ToArray


    Dim QueryStates3 = From state In States.Descendants("state")
                       Let area = state.<area>.Value
                       Order By Name Ascending
                       Select area

    AreaArr = QueryStates3.ToArray

    Dim queryStates4 = From state In States.Descendants("state")
                       Let pop = state.<population>.Value
                       Order By Name Ascending
                       Select pop

    PopArr = queryStates4.ToArray
```

> Here is where i try to output the data, the names are alphabetized just fine,
>   but none of the other data is.
>   temp is a string variable, CurrentState is a string array with length=3
>   itm is the listview item, and lstvw_Statechrt is the listview control with 4 
>   coloumns

```
    For x As Integer = 0 To 49
        temp = NameArr(x) & "," & abbArr(x) & "," & AreaArr(x) & "," & PopArr(x)
        CurrentState = temp.Split(",")
        itm = New ListViewItem(CurrentState)
        lstvw_Statechrt.Items.Add(itm)
    Next
```

So my question is does anyone have any suggestions on a way to do this?

Comment: What does your input XML look like?

Comment: Build an object that references each city with all it's pertinent information. Then deserialize the XML file to an `Array` or `List` of this object, and use `LINQ` on it.

Answer (score 0):

This would be it in C#:

```
var query = States.Descendants("state")
  .Select(s=> new { 
    name=s.<area>.Value, 
    pop = s.<population>.Value,
    abb = s.<abbreviation>.Value,
    area = s.<area>.Value
   })
 .OrderBy(s=>s.name);
```

Let's see what an online C# to vb converter comes up with:

```
Dim query = States.Descendants("state").[Select](Function(s) New With { _
    Key .name = s.area.Value, _
    Key .pop = s.population.Value, _
    Key .abb = s.abbreviation.Value, _
    Key .area = s.area.Value _
}).OrderBy(Function(s) s.name)
```